# register windows phone to app-hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile-6.5

I verified my account as student, and try to register my device the error is that Device is not registered with market place 
in fact I want to register what is the mean of this error?!
I found a solution like in this link
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/88883.aspx
here is the solution :
Log into App Hub and verify your developer account settings.

now I wanna ask what is this? how to verify developer account setting?
thanks
they told me to 
**Look under the "my dashboard" menu**
but I don't know what can i do with my dashboard when i didn't register my phone, btw so i will not have any application also..

Comment: Maybe this question could be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will find a "Windows Phone Developer Registration" tool in your start -> Programs menu, Open that tool and register your phone by following the [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769508%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), using your Apphub credentials.

Inorder to check whether your Apphub credentials(username and password) are correct, Open this [Apphub](http://windowsphone.create.msdn.com/app) link and enter your credentials. After login, it should take you to a page with the same URL(http://windowsphone.create.msdn.com/app). If it takes you to the registration steps, then your apphub account is not completed.

After making sure the above process, I suggest you the following steps(Assuming your apphub registration is successful):

1.Make sure you are able to sync some data from zune software to device.

2.Check whether you can download an app from marketplace in the device.

(These are to make sure your device is in proper condition and the problem is not with the device)

Comment: unfortunately not! because I have a verified account, I have the "Windows Phone Developer Registration", and i tried but it has the the error like that.. I must modify the account but, I don't know how

Comment: What is your exact error message? and when are you getting that error?

Comment: Device is not registered in marketPlace.please return to app-hub for more information(errorCode: 0x80043001).the error will happen when i connected the phone, zune is running and phone is unlock, i have verified account.

Comment: I think there is a way that no need to register the phone for testing application just by connecting it to PC and run zune, debug the application, any body test it?